# ECONNRESET when running migrations with NextJs PostGreSQL example project

Tags: postgresql, next.js

I am trying to teach myself Next 13 in a real-world scenario, so I ran
yarn create next-app --example with-postgres my-app-name

I have working endpoints in Postman, so I would think that the connection string I have in .env.local would be correct. However, when I try to run the migrations I get what you see here
[image]

My connection string looks like
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user_name:my_password@localhost:5432/postgres?ssl=false

Thanks for any help or pointers to resources that might help me to debug this. Note I also created a fresh copy of the example app with no changes except the connection string, and it has the same error.

Comment: It looks the app is not able to connect with the postgres database. Double check the postgres is running in the port `5432`, check the env `DATABASE_URL` read correctly, check the database username and password are correct...Also Please show us some of the code you are using, or a piece of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: As I said, my endpoints are actually working, it's just the migration in ley that's having a problem.

Comment: The example migration is here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-postgres/migrations/000-todos.js